# Using XSLT, how can I have the text insertion appear only after the last paragraph?

Tags: xslt

I need to insert a line of text after the last paragraph only in the section.

Here is my XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="xhtml:section[@property='ktp:subsection' and @data-title='Analysis']/xhtml:p">
        <xsl:param name="content-item-name"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$content-item-name = $input-qid">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                <p><i>For incorrect answer explanations, click on ‘Can other answer choices be eliminated?’ within the Strategy tab.</i></p>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<section property="ktp:subsection" typeof="ktp:feedback" class="ktp-explanation-section jasper-exclude" data-title="Analysis>
                            <p class="analysis-title"><b>Analysis</b></p>
                            <p><b>The correct answer is D.</b> This patient is status post a large anterior wall myocardial infarction <b>(MI)</b>.</p>
```

Right now it's inserting the `<p><i>For incorrect answer explanations, click on ‘Can other answer choices be eliminated?’ within the Strategy tab.</i></p>` line after each paragraph but I only want it inserted after the last paragraph. What do I need to change in my XSLT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you would handle that in the pattern e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="xhtml:section[@property='ktp:subsection' and @data-title='Analysis']/xhtml:p[last()]">
  <xsl:next-match/>
  <p><i>For incorrect answer explanations, click on ‘Can other answer choices be eliminated?’ within the Strategy tab.</i></p>
</xsl:template>
```